# Prayer time is a mess when day or night is long. What is the solution

Tags: salat, prayer-timings

[image]In Islam prayer time is calculated based on the position of sun: dawn, noon, set etc , I heard different methods to adopt to calculate prayer time when day or night time is too long or too short.

i. Follow the nearest stable country.
ii. Combine prayers : Duhar with Asar and Magrib with Isha .

But I don't feel none of them a proper solution as Islam suggested 5 times prayers to stabilize daily routines  of a Muslim and keep in memory of God throughout a day. But Muslims daily prayers is messing up their routines due to imbalance in day and night duration.

Can we adopt the following method to find prayer times where day length is too high or too short ?

```
Method :

Find the noon time where sun become 90 degree 
say it is NT

a. Fajr_End_Time =  NT - 6:00
b. Fajr_Start_Time = Fajr_End_Time - 1:30
c. Asar = NT + 3:00
d. Magrib = NT + 6:00
e. Isha = Magrib + 1:30
```

This calculation will align with day-today activities of a person. Let me know your opinions and corrections in the calculation.

Example:
Fajr Start : 4:30
Fajr End: 6:00
Noon Time: 12:00
Asar Time: 03:00
Magrib Time : 06:00
Isha Time : 07:30

Comment: And what is your question? First I don't know where you've got these strange claims or methods from? Secondly there are better solutions provided on the site.

Comment: The solutions what I hear so far are mentioned the question itself, 1. follow the nearest stable country 2. Combine prayers. Is there any other better solutions in the site?  The new method is part of my research

Comment: Yeah I've commented on that and that sounds totally wrong as no authority has ever said so as prayer times vary from location to another. And they can be witnessed by naked eye under adequate circumstances. And it's not for us to change a timing Allah made clear and well-defined in the qur'an and in the practice of his prophet. Doing so is kibr and could even be qualified as kufr. A Muslim should adapt his schedules to Allah's orders not the opposite.

Comment: I understand the spirit in you, but when you say 'well defined' it is questionable. Quran and Hadees giving some hints to some issues, we should be able to derive practical solutions from it as Islam is practical. eg, there are regions where day length is more than 20 hours, I would love to here from you the practical well defined solution from Quran to do prayer and fasting in those regions. Especially when my question itself is down voted, I was open to any suggestions but still..

Comment: You are not open, but you want to create an innovation. While the prayer times are God given. This simply is either ignorance, kufr or kibr. Further you claim (without a proof) the existence of two calculation methods which actually don't exist.

Comment: When you say I claim two calculation methods (that I am not supporting as mentioned in my question), I do not claim, I  saw it in stackexchange, I never say it is accepted or agreed by every one.

Coming back to my question, what is practical solution from your side to do prayer and fasting in regions where day length is greater than 20 hours ? 
I have edited my question by adding a diagram, to have clarity on my progressing Ijithihad, the Ijithihad is not yet finished yet.. still researching , that is why I asked as a question to collect ideas that may help my Ijithihad.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109210/discussion-between-shihab-and-medi1saif).

Comment: Sadly this is a mix between two topics fasting and praying during long days and both have been discussed and have answers on the site,

Comment: I had switched to chat room, look like you wanted to continue on comments, when you said 'answers on the site' please be specific by providing link and also mention which answer you agree out of those answers.

Answer (score 0):

The timings you are showing are very static and wouldn't represent the true timings. I would highly suggest asking a local masjid or checking what the Islamic Prayer time apps say.

Comment: I used to follow masjid and apps all based on sun's movement. But it is messing daily routines as in some season Isha is after 10 PM and Fajr is before 4 AM. The timings i mentioned is not fully static it changes according to noon time. The 90 degree of a sun is the point which can be identified by a person even from a well.

Comment: Well, I live in a stable state, and our Isha is many times after 10 and Fajr is about around 4 AM. Based on my local Masjid.

Comment: for me personally it is messing up my daily routine as I have to wait for Isha and wake up early so I get barely less sleep. Actually prayer time is to correct the daily routine not to messup. People go for literal meaning than the biggest idea concealed in Quran n hadees. Same issue is there for calendar,  a date should match to a named day, but in Islamic Calendar it is not happening. If a date is mapped to multiple days from place it place that calendar is not practical.

Comment: When I asked a technical question you gave me a conventional answer to follow local masjid or follow the apps. Think about if I am running a Masjid or I am building an app for Prayer time , and give me a proper answer. When asking a technical/research question giving a non technical answer is not recommended. 

This is the curse of the muslims they do not give any flexibly in the teachings of Allah, don't support any new researches.